# Android: notification when the user opens SMS app or phone app/missed calls list

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-appwidget

I want my AppWidgetProvider (which is a direct subclass of BroadcastReceiver) to be notified when the user reads a previously unread sms or when he opens the list of missed calls. So far I gound out that it seems to be impossible to get a Intent delivered to the BroadcastReceiver as the actions that open the (sms/phone) activities are not broadcast actions.

Is there another way to let a BroadcastReceiver know when an unread sms is read or the missed calls list is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, sorry.

Neither "unread sms is read" nor "missed calls list is opened" are part of the operating system. They are features of applications. Different implementations of those applications are found on different devices. None have any sort of broadcasts of this nature, AFAIK, mostly because none have any sort of authorized and supported API for developers to use.